# Windows boot loader corrupt on encrypted Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, encryption, bootloader

Good evening. I am looking for assistance in decrypting a HDD encrypted with Drivecrypt Plus Pack (or DCPP). In preparation for formatting, I uninstalled Drivecrypt from Windows without first removing the bootauth.

The only saving grace i have, is that i DID create the emergency USB drive which, when booted from boot options allows me to enter my decryption passwords (DriveCryptPP requires two passwords) - once i have entered the passwords the Windows logo appears, the circle spins half way around and the computer then restarts for some unknown reason. To make it more clear to those familiar with DCPP i have already attempted typing 'tools' on line two in an attempt to decrypt the HDD, but the screen just stays blank.

I have also attempted off/on around 8 times with no automatic repair option loading and just stays in a continuous loop of restart. The data contained on this HDD is of importance to me and there is a small bounty available for a solution to the problem (unsure if this is against policy, so please remove if so). Something strange happened tonight also, instead of the Windows logo appearing after entering the correct decryption passwords it went to a "text-only" version advising me to use the Windows 10 media to repair the system, this message would stay for around one minute - naturally hot swapping the SATA disk instantly came to my head however all of a sudden, it's gone back to the Windows logo restarting loop.

Comment: Likely, the only fix may be to restore the whole drive from the last full drive image.

Comment: Its gone back to the text-only screen where the decrypted HDD stays online for a minute or so, going to attempt the hot swap just waiting on another hard drive so i can make a clone before attempting it. Thanks for getting involved.